Write translatable extension methods for use inside of EF Core's .ExecuteUpdate() calls?
I have a number of entities, which inherit from an audit class: AuditableEntity:
public class AuditableEntity
{
    public DateTime? LateUpdated { get; set;}
}

...

public class Foo : AuditableEntity // An entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : AuditableEntity // Another entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}

Throughout my codebase, I'd like to use EF Core's .ExecuteUpdate() method to update my entity's properties, including the one it inherited from AuditableEntity. One way to accomplish this is as so:
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IMyDbContext _dbContext;

    public SomeService(IMyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    } 

    ...

    public void SomeMethod(){
    {
        ...

        _dbContext.Foo
            .Where(x => x.Bar == "Hello")
            .ExecuteUpdate(setter => setter
                .SetProperty(x => x.Bar, x => "Goodbye")
                .SetProperty(x => x.LastUpdated, x => DateTime.UtcNow));
        ...
    }
}

This works. However, I want to create an extension method to automatically update the LastUpdated property for me. Here's what I came up with:
public static class SetPropertyCallsExtensions
{
    public static SetPropertyCalls<TSource> SetUpdateAuditableEntityProperties<TSource>(this SetPropertyCalls<TSource> setter, DateTime now)
        where TSource : AuditableEntity
    {
        return setter.SetProperty(x => x.LastUpdated, v => now);
    }
}

I then call it like so:
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IMyDbContext _dbContext;

    public SomeService(IMyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    } 

    ...

    public void SomeMethod(){
    {
        ...

        _dbContext.Foo
            .Where(x => x.Bar == "Hello")
            .ExecuteUpdate(setter => setter
                .SetProperty(x => x.Bar, x => "Goodbye")
                .SetUpdateAuditableEntityProperties(DateTime.UtcNow);
        ...
    }
}

However, I am presented with the following exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Foo>()
    .Where(x => x.Bar == "Hello")
    .ExecuteUpdate(setter => setter
        .SetUpdateAuditableEntityProperties(
            now: DateTime.UtcNow))' could not be translated. Additional information: The 'setPropertyCalls' argument to 'ExecuteUpdate' may only contain a chain of 'SetProperty' expressing the properties to be updated. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.ExecuteUpdateAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 setPropertyCalls, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Does anyone know how to write this extension method in such a way that lets it be translated by EF Core? Or have a suggestion to make updating AuditableEntity properties easier inside .ExecuteUpdate() calls?
